# Why isn't device storage an option on my Galaxy S4?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4

Can anyone tell me how to set up the Galaxy S4 to have " storage to device " as an option to save files and pictures to my sd card? Device storage is an option, but it is not highlighted so I can't use that as an option to store files and or pictures. I got a new phone and do not want to lose my pictures. 
Thanks in advance for any advice/help given.
Cyndee

Answer (score 0):

I wonder that "device storage" turns up as an option at all, as it is not intended for direct user interaction. On internal storage, each app gets its "home directory" to write in, where they usually store their data and settings – but not e.g. your photos and documents you might wish to also access with other apps (as basically, on "device storage", each app is limited to its own directory).

Maybe you confuse this with "internal SDCard", which is the user-storage on the device (as opposed to the "external SDCard")? To get some idea on the terms, be invited to our tag-wikis on the terms [storage](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/storage/info), [internal-storage](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/internal-storage/info), and [file-system](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/file-system/info).